# Find out those managers who manage only one employee

Tags: sql, oracle

From default employees table I want to find managers who have only one employee

I have found only managers of employee

```
select  e.first_name, e.last_name, e.manager_id 
from employees e 
inner join employees m on e.manager_id = m.employee_id;
```

result should show only employees having one manager

Answer (score 1):

You could try cheking for having count(*) = 1 group by the manager_id

```
select  manager_id
from employees 
group by manager_id 
having count(*) = 1
```

and if you need the name too

```
select  e.first_name, e.last_name
from employees e 
inner join  (
    select  manager_id
    from employees 
    group by manager_id 
    having count(*) = 1 
) t on t.manager_id  = e.employee_id
```

Answer (score 1):

With this query:

```
select manager_id 
from employees
group by manager_id
having count(*) = 1
```

you get all the managers who have only 1 employee.
If you need these employees:

```
select first_name, last_name, manager_id
from employees
where manager_id in (
    select manager_id 
    from employees
    group by manager_id
    having count(*) = 1
)
```

Comment: you need to replace two `manager_id` columns with `employee_id` columns for the outer part of the second query.

Comment: Why? first_name and last_name are the employee's details.

Comment: consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=667340c39f5250cb459e86e0f10c319a) where it gives SMITH,MILLER,ADAMS but need to give CLARK,SCOTT,FORD

Comment: Why? SMITH,MILLER,ADAMS are all employees whose managers have only 1 employee.

Comment: OP says "I want to find managers who have only one employee" not "whose managers". For example, SMITH is not manager of anybody.

Comment: Exactly. If the OP needs only the manager ids then the 1st query is enough. If the requirement is to get the managers's employees then the 2nd query will do.

Comment: yes, but I couldn't explain what I want I think. Please put the query of @scaisEdge within the demo and see the result.

Comment: I think that either you or me has misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: A manager is an employee at the same time and therefore we need to filter by employee_id at the last step. Not clear ?

Comment: *result should show only employees having one manager* in the question. So I think that the result should return the employees of the managers who have only 1 employee and not the managers that have 1 employee.

Answer (score 0):

You can hierarchical query for each manager( `manager_id` column ) to go deeply for all levels,

and filter by `having count(distinct employee_id) = 1` to get managers who have only one employee.

```
select first_name, last_name, employee_id 
  from employees
 where employee_id in 
 (
    select manager_id
      from employees
    connect by prior employee_id = manager_id
     start with manager_id in ( select distinct manager_id from employees )
     group by manager_id 
     having count(distinct employee_id) = 1
 );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=721b9ff778200bc6a04aa4d5e0147693)</kbd>